# getting the first two columns from a table and turning into a list in R

Tags: r, list

I got a dataframe that looks like this

```
     V1     V2 V3    V4        V5
1 GDPD3  MEOX2  0 M0039 0.8908179
2 GDPD3 CDKN1B  0 M0039 0.8885465
3 GDPD3   BMP4  0 M0039 0.9067873
4 GDPD3   XAF1  0 M0039 0.8924670
5 GDPD3 TRIM45  0 M0039 0.9147674
6 IL6  SPAG8  0 M0039 0.9034421
```

I would like to extract the first and second columns and turn them into a list, like

```
"GPD3" "GPD3" "GPD3" "GPD3" "GPD3" "GPD3" "MEOX2" "CDKN1B" "BMP4" "XAF1" "TRIM45" "SPAG8"
```

A data frame with only one column also works for me.

The last thing I have tried was

```
brown=c(as.list(brown[1]), as.list(brown[2]))
```

Which give me a list of two lists.

I don't understand why it does not work the code below works fine

```
letters = c("a","b")
num = c("1","2")
lenum = c(letters, num)
lenum
```

lenum is exactly what I want.

```
> lenum
[1] "a" "b" "1" "2"
```

Comment: You may need `unlist(brown[1:2])` assuming they are `character` class

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select the first two columns, `unlist` to create the `vector` (instead of `list`)

```
out <- unlist(brown[1:2], use.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.matrix` + `c`

```
> c(as.matrix(df[1:2]))
 [1] "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "IL6"    "MEOX2"  "CDKN1B"
 [9] "BMP4"   "XAF1"   "TRIM45" "SPAG8"
```

or `c` with `do.call` + `unname`

```
> unname(do.call(c, df[1:2]))
 [1] "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "GDPD3"  "IL6"    "MEOX2"  "CDKN1B"
 [9] "BMP4"   "XAF1"   "TRIM45" "SPAG8"
```